# This order no longer exists for all sales orders > 1 month

Tags: magento2.2, sales-order

i just realized that i cannot open any SO which is created more than 1 month ago,
i'm getting error

> This order no longer exists

:
[image]

respective records exist in tables **sales_order** and **sales_order_grid**, order status is not deleted or cancelled, but completed...
i'm totally lost, it's looks like system "**archiving**" all SO's older than one month, but afaik there is no function like this.
will appreciate any help, thank!

Comment: Guys, anyone please?

Answer (score 0):

Actually Magento has such function. You can find it under

`Stores > Configuration > Sales > Sales > Orders, Invoices, Shipments, Credit Memos Archiving (tab)`